# how to call recursively a method in a try-catch block

Tags: java, recursion, exception

hi i have this problem i got a method that let a user insert a value representing the "quantity" of a product, now if the quantity wanted by the user is higher then the stock quanity it has to throw an exception and let the user input again the number i tryed it inserting a recursive call of the same method but even if it success it goes in an infinite loop like the exception is still "alive"

```
...
try {
    if (!lol2)
        throw new NegativeNumberException(); 
} catch (NegativeNumberException pto) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Quantità non disponibile");
    this.addToCart(cart,quant);         
}
```

EDIT i am including now all the code but it's a bit hard so sry for the "complexity" of the code

FULL CODE

```
public void addToCart(ArrayList<Utilizzabile> cart,ArrayList<Integer> quant) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
boolean lol=false;
Utilizzabile us=null;
String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Inserisci un ID prodotto:");
if (id ==null) { return;}
while (!id.matches("[0-9]+")) { //user inserts a value and the while checks for an int value inserted
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Valore inserito errato");
    id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Inserisci un ID prodotto:");
    if (id == null) { return;} }
int iden = Integer.parseInt(id);
for (Utilizzabile u: arr) { // this for loop checks if the ID inserted represents a product in the catalog
    if ((u.getId() == iden) && (u.eAcquistabile())) {
        lol =true;
        us = u; } } 
if (lol == true) { //now if the ID corresponds to an existent product it ask the user to input the quantity requested
    boolean lol2=false;
    String qua = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Inserisci un quantità da aggiungere al carrello:");
    if (qua ==null) { return;}
    while (lol2==false) {
    while (!qua.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Valore inserito errato");
        qua = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Inserisci un quantità da aggiungere al carrello:");
        if (qua == null) { return;} }
    if (qua.length()>0 && qua.length()<=8) {
    int quantit = Integer.parseInt(qua);
    for (int l=0;l<cart.size();l++) { //this for checks if in the cart were already that product and then changes the quantities only
        if ((cart.get(l).getId() == us.getId()) && (us.getRem()-quantit >0) ) {
            int num = quant.get(l)+quantit;
            quant.set(l,num);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Quantità del prodotto richiesto aggiornata");
            return;}                
    }
    if ( (us.getRem()-quantit) >0) { //checks if all went good and the quantity is avaiable
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Prodotto della quantità richiesta aggiunto al carrello");
            lol2=true;
            cart.add(us);
            quant.add(quantit);} }
    try {
        if (lol2==false)
            throw new NegativeNumberException(); }
    catch (NegativeNumberException pto){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Quantità non disponibile");
        this.addToCart(cart,quant); }       
    } }
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Prodotto non trovato");
    this.addToCart(cart,quant); }
```

}

this code essentially is a graphical section for let the user add a product to the cart and check is everything is good but i need to place an exception to check if the quantity in stock is less then the quantity wanted by the user (i ve done it without exception with no problems but this is for an exam and i just noticed that the professor wants that i have to solve this problem by using an exception

Comment: Use `if (!lol2)` instead of `if (lol2 == false)`

Comment: lol2 ? this make no sense, At least provide a meaningful variable name so others can assume what will be the value of that variable on which cases. Also it is a good practice to do so, then your code make sense even in few years later

Comment: @Christian doesn't change anything

Comment: It was just a recommendation, good programing practice. Please give more context, I mean, what's the recursive method? where is that `try-catch` located?

Comment: @RytisI: please make sure your edits don't break the syntax

Comment: Dear god, you really need to work on your code style. I don't even know where to begin x( But I guess you could start on spacing...

Comment: Neither exception handling or recursion needs to be a part of the solution to what you're trying to do. You can do this with loops and if/else statements. This code is quite frankly horrible.

Comment: @Rytis yes mate i am sry it was perfect understandable but i needed to make some changings that rly took me so much i couldn't fix the syntax  so i am trying to solve problems before start to correcting the style

Comment: @Seth yes i know i did in fact but i have to do it with an exception, because this is for a project and the professor asked that part have to be handled with an exception

Comment: @TheBigBoss also try to comment your code while you are writing it. Not just for you, but for people you show the code.

Comment: @TheBigBoss: Off topic, but.. I don't know how you write your code, but you should use some sort of IDE that handles code formatting for you. I would recommend IntelliJ Idea from JetBrains. Best of luck :)

Comment: @TheBigBoss: Now on topic, add a breakpoint at the beginning of the method and step through it to see why it falls into the unwanted loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good to use recursion for that, because after "n" invocations you can receive StackOverFlowError. And I agree with @laune. 
Thus I recommend to use loop. For example:

```
while (true){
    // lol2 here is TRUE if was entered correct value and false if not.
    if (lol2)
        break;
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Quantità non disponibile");
        this.addToCart(cart,quant);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i agree too , i did it without but i noticed that the prof wanted it handled with an exception so i have to change it but probably in the way of how i did it's pretty hard to implement it and i have to change so much code

Comment: Here is example http://pastebin.com/JHbqZaup
As you can see I use Exception instead a Boolean checking.

Answer (score 2):

Never use exceptions to control the regular or almost regular flow of control. It's bad programming style.

Use some do statement to repeat the dialog until a satisfactory input is achieved.

Due to lack of context, no code is provided. (Where is that recursive call??)

**Later**
There is room for exception handling, though. You could throw away pattern matching and length check and catch NumberFormatException.

```
Integer quantity = null;
do {
    String id ... dialogue
    try {
        quantity = Integer.parseInt( id );
        if( quantity <= 0 ) throw new NumberFormatException( "only positive integers" );
    } catch(  NumberFormatException nfe ){
        ... error dialogue;
        quantity = null;
    }
} until( quantity != null );
```

Answer (score 2):

insert try catch into do while loop.

when user insert correct value stop loop
E.g

```
  int a=10;
  do{
        try{
             if(a<20)   
                 throw new NegativeNumberException(); 
             else
                  break;
           }catch (NegativeNumberException pto){

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Quantità non disponibile");
              //enter quantity again
              // a=20;
           }
    }while(true);
```